# Return URL concept in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, return-value

My requirement is this. whenever i would not be login in my site then never access a web page. but the url added after the login page url means (return url) and after successful login into my site the page redirect to same page which i have to access and entered into address bar.

Example: i have to access page **http://localhost:14334/User/userdetail.aspx** without login. the page returns to me on **http://localhost:14334/Login.aspx**. but i want that the page returns to me on **http://localhost:14334/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUser%2fuserdetail.aspx**

Comment: What you describe is automatically done for you by the framework. Read up on Forms Authentication on MSDN. Pay attention to the Web.config sections required to enable Forms authentication on your site.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like all you are missing is the call to redirect:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UsernameTextbox.Text, NotPublicCheckBox.Checked);
```

See this for more information - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The return URL in the `ASP.NET` login page returns to the location upon a successful login, if the default `ASP.NET` template is not modified.